# JavsSript RegEx to match any ")" not surrounded by tags, i.e. any ") "which is not ">)<"

Tags: javascript, regex

The closest I can get is:

```
/[^>]\)[^<]/g
```

but this will only match the ")" if it has a character before and after. I need it to match a ")" surrounded by anything except ">" and "<" including nothing, so just a single ")" would be matched.

Hope I've made sense.

All help greatly appreciated, thanks.

Edit: Ok maybe I wasn't clear, sorry! I'll try to clarify.

I'm only interesting in matching ")" which don't have ">" immediately before it and "<" immediately after it. So,

- ) = match
- >)< = no match
- >sdfsdf)sdfsdf< = match
- >sdfsdf)< = match
- >)sdfsdf< = match
- xx>)< = no match

I know it's a weird situation!

Comment: So no matching `>sdfsd)sfsdf<`?

Comment: @sshashank124 `any “) ”which is not “>)<”`

Comment: @ Lugia101101 yes that's right

Answer (score 2):

Use alternation `|` to allow the beginning of string `^` before the `)` and the end of string `$` after it.

```
/(?:^|[^>])\)(?:$|[^<])/g
```

Comment: This is close but it doesn't matter if the ")" has just one < and not >. I need any ")" that is not exactly ">)<". I've edited the question to try and make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you want:

`([^>]|^)\)([^<]|$)/g`

You can see the demo here: http://regex101.com/r/kA0cE3

Comment: I need any ")" that is not exactly ">)<", so the last 2 examples in that demo should match. I've edited the question to try and make it clearer.

Comment: @MattHerbstritt, In that case, why don't you do something like. Find `)` in string if `>)<` is not in the string. It would be ___much___ easier than `regex`

Comment: Yeah ok. I wanted to use str.match( ">)<" ).length to try and count how many times it occurs in the string without using loops but if there is no simple and effective regex then yeah, as you say, it might be best to do it the other way. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Match the beginning or the end of the string also and you'll be okay. e.g. `/(?:[^>]|^)\)(?:[^<]|$)/g`